# Sent update to client about progress of a long running task from view

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a page on my website where user can upload a xlsx file using ajax, on backend I read the file, do a little processing and start inserting its rows one by one in my database. If the files uploaded by the user gets quite large, entering new values in the database can take a while. Therefore I want to give user real-time progress update on their screen, eg. -

```
Found 100 rows of data
Interesting 1/100.
Interesting 2/100.
...
Interesting 100/100.
Done.
```

My View:

```
import pandas as pd

def myView(self, request):
    """Handle POST requests, save all data provided in excel file."""
    excel_file = request.FILES.get('excel_one')
    excel_df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    data_format = ['Option_1', 'Option_2', 'Option_3', 'Option_4',]
    try:
        formatted_df = excel_df[data_format]
    except KeyError as error:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': str(error), })
    # forloop to create model objects
    for i, v in formatted_df.iterrows():
        # do a lot of data validating and stuff first
        MyModels.objects.create(arguments)
        print(f'Created object {i+1}/{len(formatted_df)}!'  # Want to to be sent to html page in real time
    return JsonResponse({'success': True, })
```

I am making an ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({  // variables url, data, etc. contain the expected stuff
    async: false,
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(d){
        if(data.success){
            console.log(d);
         }
         else{
             $('.log').append('<p><b>Error:</b> '+ d.message +'</p>')
         }
     },
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
});
```

Saving data in database and everything else is working as expected but I just can't figure out how to send real-time updates to ajax. One possible solution I can think of is to implement web sockets instead of normal http requests, but I am in a little hurry so is there any way to do it with simple js and django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to resort to WebSocket, you can try:

- the quick and dirty way: have your JS poll another API view to check the status
- Have you heard of [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects)? I've never used it, but might be worth a try. You can see an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-csv-files).

Comment: not a fan of js so I will try `StreamingHttpResponse` first, if everything works out I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that will help so much actually, by the look of it, you'd have to do some parsing client side, I think...

Comment: I ended up using websockets as it was required in other parts of my project too.

Answer (score 1):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) will help here like anything.

- Just write a function for our time-consuming task, set this up as a celery task
- Return a process id or file whatever immediately as a response for the first API
- Poll on a second API from ur ajax with this id, get the expected result on this API

Please note: Don't keep any HTTP request open for more than a specific period of time, this will impact the performance seriously.